# Handle nested properties of Object in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, object, lodash

Hi I'm writing a module in NodeJS in a OOP style.

I have multiples simples objects that contains primitive data and multiple complex objects that contain other objects.

```
const Simple = function Simple() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

Simple.prototype.getArea = function() {
    return this.x * this.y;
}


const Complex = function Complex() {
    this.ownProp = 0;
    this.nestedProp = new Simple();
    this.otherNestedProp = new otherSimple();
}


Complex.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
    this[key] = value;
}

Complex.prototype.otherSet = function(value) {
    Object.assign(this, value);
}
```

My problem is that users who will use my API can break things by doing this:

```
let simple = new Simple();
simple.getArea(); // 0

let complex = new Complex();
complex.nestedProp.getArea(); // 0
complex.set('nestedProp', {x: 5, y: 6});
complex.nestedProp.getArea(); // THROW  <----

let complex = new Complex();
complex.nestedProp.getArea(); // 0
complex.set({nestedProp: {x: 5, y: 6});
complex.nestedProp.getArea(); // THROW  <----
```

**Is there a lodash function to only assign values of such nested Object.**
**Or is there a good way to manage this kind of problems?**

Note: I could check for `instanceof` but I have a lot of modules, and I don't want to manage each specific case.

Comment: what you are trying with `otherSet ` function?

Comment: Are you ready to migrate your project to use TypeScript? That will solve your problem of allowing only specific type of object assignment.

Comment: what you want exactly, people will be allowed to do `complex.set('nestedProp', {x: 5, y: 6});` or not? even `complex.nestedProp = {x: 10, y: 90}` this or not?

Comment: You should try typescript.for oops like implementation. And for this problem you can function that only set x or y value and if inner object is immutable so create function that two parameters and create new inner object.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee It's an alternative method to directly set passing a plain object. I don't want people to be allowed to do complex.nested = ... (I would like to throw if they do so). I would probably use Proxy object

Comment: @ChandreGowda I considered Typescript, but decided to not use it, maybe I should. I was wondering about community.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you think passing something like `{x: 1, y:2}` to Complex.set will magically make x and y end inside of Simple. I think you are confused about how Javascript works, no offense meant.

Here's an implementation that would make things work roughly the way you seem to want.

```
const Simple = function Simple() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

Simple.prototype.getArea = function() {
    return this.x * this.y;
}

Simple.prototype.set = function (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}


const Complex = function Complex() {
    this.nestedProp = new Simple();
}


Complex.prototype.set = function(props) {
    this.nestedProp.set(props.x, props.y);
}

let complex = new Complex();
complex.nestedProp.getArea(); // 0
complex.set({x: 5, y: 6});
complex.nestedProp.getArea(); // 30
```

The properties x and y are passed explicitly from Complex to Simple until they end where they should. You can either pass x and y as separate parameters (see Simple's `set`) or as properties of an object (see Complex's `set`).

But if you thought x and y would make it all the way to the end by themselves you need to study basic OOP before writing code; again, no offense meant.

Comment: No offense at all, but I know how Javascript works. I just dont know about OOP  best practices in Javascript since you've so much freedom. Ofc the example I give you is pretty simple, but my code is much more complex, and I don't want to have too much specific cases to handle in each setter.

Comment: My apologies then, I hope my answer was of some help!

Comment: ^^ I had the same idea at start, but it's so much boilerplate and maintenance when you have 100+ objects depending on each other.
But thanks bro ;)